# Туристський і туристичний

Tags: вживання-слів

В Карпатах помітила табличку «туристська база відпочинку».

На порталі https://ukr-mova.in.ua знайшла картинку:

[image: Туристичний: організація, бюро, клуб, секція, похід, мандрівка, спорт, сезон — Туристський: автобус, намет, група, база, велосипед, костюм, відпочинок, маршрут, пісня]

А що стосується бази відпочинку чи табору — туристичний/а?

Comment: 1. Бажано давати пряму ланку, де саме бачили [зобразу](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/turustuchnuj-i-turustskuj). 2. Там сливе під кожним зобразом є опис: _Туристичний – який стосується туризму, подорожей. Туристський – який стосується туриста, туристів, призначений для туристів._

Answer (score 1):

Тетяна Коць у статті ["Туристичний-туристський"](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine61-25.pdf):

> Вживання слова туристський передбачає сполучуваність із назвами певних реалій життя туристів: **туристська
>   база**.

На сайті [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53410/32494.html) також знаходимо:

> Туристський. Який стосується туриста, туристів: туристський намет, туристський автобус, туристський похід (похід туристів), туристський сезон, **туристський табір**, **туристська база**, туристська група, туристська подорож, туристська путівка.

Також знаходимо у статті [Уроки державної мови (з газети «Хрещатик»)](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53410/25781.html):

> Варіант туристичний неприродний з низкою лексем, які змістово поєднуються з поняттям “турист”: **база**.

Отже, правильно **туристська база, туристський табір**.